# MySQL Query returns string instead of numeric value

Tags: mysql

I want to multiply 4 with number of faults if faulttype='business' and faultseverity='fatal', using query listed below;

```
Select faulttype, IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='fatal', 1,0)* 4 FROM tbl_fault WHERE product='DAS' AND faultdistribution='missed'
 group by faulttype
```

I am getting result **business** instead of numeric value, What should be corrected in this query?

Regards

Comment: Which column of your result set are you trying to retrieve? The first is still `faulttype`, the second will be the numeric value.

Comment: I want to retrieve the numeric value from 2nd column.

Comment: Yes, but you should show us the code, not the query. The problem must be there.

Comment: $cmsc= mysql_query("Select faulttype, IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='fatal', 1,0)* 4 FROM tbl_fault WHERE product='DAS' AND faultdistribution='missed'
 group by faulttype");
while ($cresult = mysql_fetch_array ($cmsc))
$fat[0] = $cresult[0];

Comment: `$cresult[0]`: the first index is the first column. Use `$cresult[1]` for the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Select CASE faulttype WHEN faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='fatal' THEN 1*4 ELSE 0 END AS rez FROM tbl_fault WHERE product='DAS' AND faultdistribution='missed'
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Select faulttype, sum(IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='fatal', 1,0))*4 FROM tbl_fault WHERE product='DAS' AND faultdistribution='missed'
 group by faulttype;
```

[For reference see the sql fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52197/6)